# How can I return a custom response for non-existent endpoints?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, exceptionhandler

how can I return JSON response for queries to non-existent endpoints?

For example: query to */api/rock?q=123*, but the api have */api/paper* only, and then the server return *{'error': 'endpoint not found'}* or something.

I'm using Django Rest Framework 3.14.0, Django 4.1.7, help please.

I checked *exception_handler* in views.py, but how can I return a custom response for non-existent endpoints?

I've read the documentation, but I can't get this done.
Returns the default response for Django resources not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, my intention was, having given endpoints, eg: */api/paper*, when the api receives requests for other non-existent endpoints, the server will return a json response like *{"error": "endpoint does not exist".}*.

How I solved it:

In the root of the project, in *urls.py* of the root, added *handler404 = 'utils.views.error_404'*

- Project structure:

```
|- root
|   |- urls.py
|
|- utils
|  |- views.py
|
|- app
```

- *views.py*

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def error_404(request, exception):
    message = "Resource not found."
    return JsonResponse(data={'message': message}, status=404)


def error_500(exception):
    message = "D\'oh, something was wrong."
    return JsonResponse(data={'error': message}, status=404)
```

- *urls.py*

```py
handler404 = 'utils.views.error_404'
handler500 = 'utils.views.error_500'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should catch all requests under "/api" and give the proper response.

```py
from flask import render_template, jsonify

# assuming you already have your app initiated.

@app.route("/api", defaults={'path': ''})
@app.route("/api/<path:path>")
def api(path):
  try:
    return render_template(path+"/index.html") # try to match the API endpoint
  except: # endpoint not found
    return jsonify({'error': 'endpoint not found'})
```

Comment: Please, describe what and why you are suggesting.

Comment: @NixonSparrow Yes, I wrote the answer quickly and have updated it with additional explanations.